# Using one dataset in many forms

Tags: vb.net, forms, dataset

I am using vb.net to load data from sql server database. I have defined a dataset in my module
and want to use it in many forms `Public dsDataset As DataSet`. When I load the main form I load the options that are likely to be the same in all the forms like the departments and sections, so that I do not have to load them again in all the forms. When Navigating from main form to an other form I pass this dataset in a the form constructor.

In the main form I am loading these options:

```
Sub loadOptions()
        Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
        Dim sql As String

        Try
            sqlConn = New SqlConnection(connString)
            sqlConn.Open()

            sql = " select depId, name from DEPARTMENT "
            da = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, sqlConn)
            da.Fill(dsDataset, "department")


            sql = " select select depId, sectionId, name from SECTION "
            da = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, sqlConn)
            da.Fill(dsDataset, "section")

            '----------------------------------------------------------------------

            sqlConn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            sqlConn.Close()
            MsgBox(Err.Description)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Then lets say I have printers form where I load data from from the database and use the option in the dsDataset instead of loading them again. I pass the dataset as follows:

```
Dim printers As frmPrinters = New frmPrinters(dsDataset)
printers.ShowDialog()
```

and in the printers form I have a constructor as follows:

```
Sub New(ByRef dsDataset As DataSet)
        InitializeComponent()

        cmbDepartment.DataSource = dsDataset.Tables("department")
        cmbDepartment.DisplayMember = "name"
        cmbDepartment.ValueMember = "depId"

        cmbSection.DataSource = dsDataset.Tables("section")
        cmbSection.DisplayMember = "name"
        cmbSection.ValueMember = "sectionId"

    End Sub
```

and load all the printers to the dataset with no problem:

```
 sql = "select * from printer where printerId=" & printerId
 daPrinter = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, sqlConn)
 daPrinter.Fill(dsDataset, "printer")
 dgvPrinters.DataSource = dsDataset.Tables("printers")
```

Now when I double click any of the printers I go an other form to load the details of that particular printer as follows:

```
printerId = dgvPrinters.Rows(dgvPrinters.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(0).Value
printerMode = "modify"
Dim printer As New frmPrinter(dsDataset)
printer.ShowDialog()
```

In the new form I use the same constructor above but the problem happens there. The following error comes:

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: dataSet
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code to see which variable is exactly `null`?

Comment: one thing, dsDataset value is Nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are saving the dsDataset anywhere in your constructor. For example in a private variable. My guess is that inside frmPrinters you will have a public dsDataSet variable which you never set to anything.

So what you should do is the following:

Create a private dsDataSet variable in frmPrinter called _dsDataset:

```
Private _dsDataset As DataSet
```

In the constructor do this:

```
_dsDataset = dsDataset
```

And finally in the doubleclick event send the private variable:

```
Dim printer As New frmPrinter(_dsDataset)
```

And then you should be fine.

Comment: Got your idea, I created a public dataset _dsDataset in my printers form and then set it = to the dsDataset sent from the main form. But it says the same problem

Comment: Could it be that you Fill the table "printer" but set the DataGridView to have the table "printers" as source?

Comment: Ok got it. As you said in your solution: "My guess is that inside frmPrinters you will have a public dsDataSet variable which you never set to anything". That is right. Some how I forgot to delete the private daDataset in my frmPrinters and logically that dataset will have the priority to be used inside the frmPrinters. I deleted it and things worked perfectly. Thank you

Comment: Do I need to rebind the controls again?